# How to iterate through a directory of images using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Here's my situation:

I have a directory of folders that contain image files inside them. For example: images/(ID)/(ID)-1 (or 2, 3, etc.).jpg. Where (ID) is variable (I have hundreds of IDs within the images directory).

I'm new to React and still trying to get my way through how to use loops in it. I've tried several different approaches and none have seemed to worked on this specific case.

How would I go about constructing a loop that will iterate over each folder, dynamically, and render the images inside each folder? I have a carousel that I want to call this loop in.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT: I've tried working with these two solutions:

[How to iterate images on React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382713/how-to-iterate-images-on-react)

With my own context:

```
const images = [{ src: "./images" + ID, alt: "Your description here 1" }];

// ...

{
  images.map(function(imageProps) {
    return (
      <li key={imageProps.src}>
        <img src={imageProps.src} alt={imageProps.alt} />
      </li>
    );
  });
}
```

And

[Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)

With my own context:

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().map(r);
}

const images = importAll(
  require.context("./images" + ID, false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
);
```

With the latter, I figured out that within `require.context`, you can't have a dynamic variable within the argument otherwise it just throws you an error. The first example, it told me that .map wasn't a function. The error wasn't much help.

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet so far.

Comment: This is one:

`  const images = { src: "./images" + (ID) + "/" + (ID) }

                        {Object.keys(images.map(function(imageProps) {
                          return (
                            <li key={ imageProps.src }>
                              <img src={ imageProps.src } />
                            </li>
                          );
                        })}`

Comment: edit your post with the code.

Comment: See edits. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how many images are there in each folder?

Comment: It varies. Most of them hold 4 images, but I've seen some folders hold 19.

Comment: How the **server** exposes the list? Because client (unless you're rendering server side) cannot browse (generally speaking) the server directories...

Comment: I am using a React app called Searchkit. It connects with my server using their SearchkitManager component. I have a JSON file that has a particular field that is being used as an identification number, and it mirrors the ID numbers given to the photo files.

Right now, I am able to display one image from the folder using this field (or multiple if I just reuse the code over and over, but then that leads to having dups in the carousel and the code is ugly as hell.) What I'm trying to get is a piece of logic that will go into the folder and render all of the relevant images, and nothing more.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64324949/best-way-to-loop-images-in-react

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue trying to implement this in React. But I was able to do it using JavaScript on HTML. Seems iterating over a directory to display its content is not possible with React. The only solution so far has been to import and map.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).