# Best way to loop images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a project with create-react-app and I have a folder called images inside the source.
I want to loop inside the images folder and display them.

So far my code look like this:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import images from './images/wd/'

const listOfImages = []

class Myloop extends Component {
  importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r)
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    listOfImages = this.importAll(require.context(images, false, /\.(png)$/))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ul>
          <li>
            {listOfImages.map((images, index) => (
              <img src={images} key={index} alt="info"></img>
            ))}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Myloop
```

After saving the file I have the following message on the terminal:

> Module not found: Can't resolve './images/wd/' in
> '/mywebsite/src/components'

I'm not sure what is wrong, but any help will be great.

Comment: Have a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack

Comment: `require.context(images` should probably be `require.context('./images/wd/'`

Comment: @Dominik. I have tried many of those methods and didn't work at all. There is no webpack.config.js in the latest versions.

Comment: @cbr, the path was originally as you described, but even so, the error of "Module not found: Can't resolve './images/wd/' in '/mywebsite/src/components'" still persists.

Comment: what is "/wd/" in the images path?

Comment: Is the `images/wd/` directory under `src/components/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer [Dynamically import images from a directory using webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42118296/dynamically-import-images-from-a-directory-using-webpack)
You cannot import the whole directory at the same time with only "import"

```
    function importAll(r) {
      return r.keys().map(r);
    }
    
    const images = importAll(
      require.context("./images/wd", false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/)
    );
```

UPD: So in your case remove `import`, swap `images` with url and add `listOfImages` to the state

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Myloop extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { listOfImages: [] };
  }
  importAll(r) {
    return r.keys().map(r);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const list = this.importAll(
      require.context("./images/wd", false, /\.(png)$/)
    );
    this.setState({
      listOfImages: list
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <ul>
          <li>
            {this.state.listOfImages.map((image, index) => (
              <img src={image} key={index} alt="info"></img>
            ))}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Myloop;
```

Comment: That's the right one. Thanks @Julka. I implemented and it works like a charm.

Comment: Although, if my images folder is outside the components folder, it doesn't load. Any idea?

Comment: @ffas, change path from "./images/wd" to needed